# Measuring CPU time per-thread on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, cpu-usage

I'm developing a long-running multi-threaded Python application for Windows, and I want the process to know the CPU time that each of its threads has taken.  I can get the overall times for the entire process with [os.times()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.times) but I need to know the per-thread times.

I know that there are external tools such as the Sysinternals Process Explorer, but my program itself needs to have this information.  If I were on Linux, I look in the `/proc` filesystem, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040257/measuring-amount-of-cpu-time-taken-by-a-piece-of-code-in-c-on-unix-linux).  If I were writing C code, I'd use the `GetThreadTimes` call, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393006/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-per-thread-on-windows-win32).

So how can I accomplish this on Windows using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`win32process.GetThreadTimes`

You want the [Python for Windows Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to do hairy windows things.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply use yappi. (https://code.google.com/p/yappi/) It transparently uses GetThreadTimes() if CPU clock type is selected for profiling.

See here also for an example: https://code.google.com/p/yappi/wiki/YThreadStats_v082